# Infimum of norms of elements in a hyperplane

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

In a Banach space X, given a norm one bounded linear functional $f$ and $c\in \mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$, define $H = \big\{ x\in X \,\vert\, f(x) = c\big\}$ and $\inf H$ = $\inf_{h\in H} \|h\|$.

1. Is there a necessary condition for $\inf H = \vert\, c\,\vert$?

**Update**: In $X$, we always have $\inf H = \vert\, c\,\vert$. Check [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450759).

Comment: $\inf H=|c|$ is always true.

Comment: Could you provide a proof or a reference to the proof? To prove it there must be an $h$ in the hyperplane such that $\|h\| = \vert\,c \,\vert$ but I cannot see how to find one.

Comment: There need not be such an element $h$. It is enough if there is a sequence $(h_n)$ in $H$ such that $\|h_n\|\to |c|$.

Comment: Indeed, but looking for an $h_n \in H$ with $\|h_n\|$ that is $\epsilon$ around $\vert\, c \,\vert$ is equivalent to (or has a similar solution) finding $h\in H$ with $\|h\| = \vert\, c\,\vert$ although I doubt that $\inf H$ can always be obtained.

Comment: Check this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450759

Comment: What you are saying amounts to saying that every set of real numbers which is bounden below has a  smallest element. This is false.  Does $(0,1)$ have a smallest element?